# Why isn't the branch name shown in the git history?

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a code that I downloaded with git. In the code I create a new branch for my modifications with the following command:

```
git checkout -b branch_5
```

After finishing the edit of the files, I made a local commit

```
git commit -a
```

And then I created the patch. But I m not able to see the name of the new branch in the history neither in the generated patch file.

Any explaination ? Am I missing something in the creation of the new branch?

Where I can find the information concerning the new branch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to see branch names in Git's log output, you can use the `--decorate` option of `git log`:

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate
```

You can read more about [`git log` options at the official Linux Kernel Git documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html).

Answer (score 2):

Branches are meta information. A branch simply points to a commit in your repository. No commit can therefore know anything about which branch it is on. What exactly is your expectation? What do you want to do with the branch information?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your best place to start is in the documentation for branching: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-What-a-Branch-Is

Since commits can exist in multiple branches, there isn't a simple way to display branch information in a commit message. You could try `gitk` to look at your full revision tree history.

Patches have a similar problem -- the commits in question could be in multiple branches. A patch is just a set of instructions for where to look to make changes to a file (or files), so it exists independent of specific branches.